# using PHP switch control statement to list each table column and row in MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am new to PHP.
Please I need help with the code below.I am trying to use PHP switch statement to display table data from MySQL database based on the selection of a particular table. I have 2 PHP files (index.php and table_data.php). The file index.php has a function that list all the tables from the database with onclick function to list the row and columns of a particular table. The second file table_data.php contains the switch statement but the switch statement does not list the table data when a particular table is selected, it does not list the row and columns of the table. I Think the problem is with the switch statement. Please help and thanks in advance. below is the table_data.php file

```
                <?php
            include_once 'connect.php';

            function showtable()
            {
                $dbname  = 'Database';
                echo "TABLE NAMES";
                $tables = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `" . $dbname . "`");
                while (list($table) = mysql_fetch_row($tables))
                {
                      echo "<div onclick='table()' title='click to show table data'>$table</div>";    

                }
            }

            ?>
            <body>
            <script>
            function table()
            {
            document.getElementById('video').src='table_data.php';
            }
            </script>
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="1" id="content">
            <tr>
            <td width="20%" valign="top" bgcolor="#0033FF">
            <?php showtable();?>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" >
            <iframe id="video" src="table_data.php">
            </iframe>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            </body></html>
```

Comment: You have a variable scope issue - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. You need to add the table as a function parameter -> `showtabledata($table)`

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated.  Look into mysqli or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this code, use showtabledata($table) , pass $table through function

```
     <?php
     include_once 'connect.php';
     $table = '';

     function showtabledata($table)
     {


         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$table);
         if (!$result)
         {
         die("Query to show fields from table failed");
         }

         $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

         echo "<div class='sidemenu'>Table: {$table}</div>";
         echo "<table><tr>";

         for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
         {

         $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
         echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
         }
         echo "</tr>\n";

         while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
         {

             echo "<tr>";

             foreach($row as $cell) {
                 echo "<td>$cell</td>";   
             }
             echo "</tr>\n";
         }
         mysql_free_result($result);

         echo "</table>";


     }


     switch($table)
     {
         case '1':
            $table = 'table1';
            echo "table not available";
            break;
         case '2':
            $table = 'table2';
            showtabledata($table);
            break;
         case '3':
            $table = 'table3';
            showtabledata($table);
            break;
         case '4':
         default:
            $table = 'table4';
            showtabledata($table);

     }
```

?>

Comment: Code dumps with no explanation are crappy answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the variable `$table` is not visible inside the function `showtabledata()`. So you can either import (sort of) the variable inside the function like this :

```
$table = '';

function showtabledata()
{
    /* other code */

    global $table;

    /* other code */
}
```

or can pass the variable as an argument to the function like `showtabledata($table)` as suggested by Sean, like this :

```
$table = '';

function showtabledata($table)
{

    // use $table

}
```

Have a look at [Language variables scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)